# How do i send automatic emails with front end javascript?

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid, mailgun

Is there any way to send automatic emails from a website with pure-front-end javascript and not node.js? Mailgun, Maildrill, and Sendgrid all only use node.js or php? Is it possible to do this without server side code? The reason i need to do this is because, I can't figure out how to add node.js to an existing website project, and also, node.js is very confusing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can absolutely send email from client side code. Most of the services you mentioned provide an HTTP endpoint for doing so, and sending HTTP requests from client-side code is straight-forward.

However, doing so is almost always a bad idea. Client-side code by nature is available to your users, therefore any credentials you might use to send email would also be exposed to your users. Your account would be quickly compromised and banned. This is the same reason why sending email directly from a mobile app is a bad idea; anyone with a proxy can find the credentials.

Comment: If those services provide a HTTP endpoint, then they are a HTTP server by definition. I stand by my claim: you need a server. Granted, it does not need to be a server under your control.